# box-shadow as text background

Tags: css

I have an element with inline background color made with `box-shadox`, like this:

```css
.overlay {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 red, -10px 0 0 red;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.overlay>span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <span>Category</span>
</div>
```

However, since the text also needs a border and border radius, I added an inner span.
As a consequence I need to add more box-shadow to top and bottom, but how?

I tried adding more layers to the `box-shadow` like this:

```
box-shadow: 10px 0 0 red, -10px 0 0 red, 0 10px 0 red, 0 -10px 0 red;
```

but it doesn't look good. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the expected result should look like, and why you have/want to use box shadow for that instead of border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spread` property in `box-shadow` to display shadow around every 4 edges of the element.

```css
.overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px red;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.overlay>span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <span>Category</span>
</div>
```

And there are [tools](https://box-shadow.dev/) for `box-shadow` that you can use to achieve the best form you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please add use display: inline-block for displaying top and bottom box shadow. it will work

```css
.overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 2px -1px 0 10px red;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.overlay>span {
   display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin:2px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <span>Category</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you can also refer a link https://jsfiddle.net/dindayaldhakar/pzy9tqow/1/

Comment: If you want to show border-radius in the box-show, then you can add border-radius in the overlay class